# Odata $expand not working in Dynamic EdmModel Creation

Tags: .net, odata

I have done the dynamic edm Model creation by taking reference from https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApiCore/DynamicEdmModelCreation .

I have added the odata query options to the above project. $filter, $top, $count, $select(without  expand) are working successfully. But when I query `~/odata/Products?$expand=DetailInfo` - it is not returning any value for DetailInfo. Can anybody help me this above problem

```
 EdmEntityObject entity = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("Name", "abc");
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("ID", 1);
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("DetailInfo", CreateDetailInfo(88,"abc_detailinfo", entity.ActualEdmType)); 
 collection.Add(entity);
 entity = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("Name", "def");
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("ID", 2);
 entity.TrySetPropertyValue("DetailInfo", CreateDetailInfo(99, "def_detailinfo", entity.ActualEdmType));
 collection.Add(entity);
```

After executing the above code the collection holds 2 values each value have 3 properties 2 structural properties(name , id) and 1 navigational property which holds value of DetailInfo.

**Present Output:**

`[{"Name":"abc","ID":1},{"Name":"def","ID":2}]}`

**Expected Output:**

```
[{"Name":"abc","ID":1, "DetailInfo":{"ID":88,"Title":"abc_detailinfo"}},{"Name":"def","ID":2, "DetailInfo":{"ID":99,"Title":"def_detailinfo"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Dynamic EDM model creation you have to implement the logic to apply the ODataQueryOptions yourself.

This means your GET(id) method in your controller looks something like below.

```
    public IEdmEntityObject Get(string key)
    {
        // Get entity type from path.
        ODataPath path = Request.ODataFeature().Path;
        IEdmEntityType entityType = (IEdmEntityType)path.EdmType;

        // Create an untyped entity object with the entity type.
        EdmEntityObject entity = new EdmEntityObject(entityType);

        string sourceString = Request.GetDataSource();
        DataSourceProvider.Get(sourceString, key, entity);


        IEdmModel model = Request.GetModel();
        ODataQueryContext queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, entityType, path);
        ODataQueryOptions queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);

        // Apply query options here.

        return entity;
    }
```

This means your GET method in your controller looks something like below.

```
    public EdmEntityObjectCollection Get()
    {
        // Get entity set's EDM type: A collection type.
        ODataPath path = Request.ODataFeature().Path;
        IEdmCollectionType collectionType = (IEdmCollectionType)path.EdmType;
        IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType = collectionType.ElementType.AsEntity();

        // Create an untyped collection with the EDM collection type.
        EdmEntityObjectCollection collection =
            new EdmEntityObjectCollection(new EdmCollectionTypeReference(collectionType));

        string sourceString = Request.GetDataSource();
        // Add untyped objects to collection.
        DataSourceProvider.Get(sourceString, entityType, collection);


        IEdmModel model = Request.GetModel();
        ODataQueryContext queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, collectionType.AsElementType(), path);
        ODataQueryOptions queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, Request);

        // Apply query options here.

        return collection;
    }
```